# How to efficiently count distinct values between all date combinations

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use pySpark to process website visitor datasets, where each user is assigned a unique identifier.

| Visit timestamp | User id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:23:44.123456 | aaa |
| 2022-01-02 11:22:44.123456 | aaa |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:44.123456 | bbb |
| 2022-01-01 12:22:44.123456 | bbb |
| 2022-01-05 13:23:44.123456 | abc |
| 2022-01-03 14:22:44.123456 | ccc |
| 2022-01-04 10:23:44.123456 | ddd |
| 2022-01-01 11:22:44.123456 | eee |

I am searching for an efficient way to count the number of distinct `user_ids` between all possible date combinations, looking for an output in the following form:

| Start date | End date | unique visitors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-05 | 6 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 | 3 |

Additionally, would need to store intermediary data in such a way that this can be run incrementally as new data comes in.

I can easily use the `approx_count_distinct` function to compute the number of distinct visitors for any given day, but that does not solve the start / end data and incremental load needs.

Thanks!

Comment: The task you're presenting is known as "sessionization" and is not easily solved. Some form has been implemented to Spark recently.
You can read more about it here:
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(web_analytics)
- https://databricks.com/fr/session_eu19/using-apache-spark-to-solve-sessionization-problem-in-batch-and-streaming
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.session_window.html

Comment: @Gaarv agree not an easy task. But the new function `session_window` introduced since Spark 3.2 is not meant to handle "combinations" of dates like the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

> I am searching for an efficient way to count the number of distinct user ids all possible date combinations

All possible combinations of dates means you're almost doing a cross join which is not efficient. Maybe you could consider using cumulative count instead?

---

Using this input dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("2022-01-01 10:23:44.123456", "aaa"), ("2022-01-02 11:22:44.123456", "aaa"),
    ("2022-01-01 11:00:44.123456", "bbb"), ("2022-01-01 12:22:44.123456", "bbb"),
    ("2022-01-05 13:23:44.123456", "abc"), ("2022-01-03 14:22:44.123456", "ccc"),
    ("2022-01-04 10:23:44.123456", "ddd"), ("2022-01-01 11:22:44.123456", "eee"),
], ["visit_timestamp", "user_id"])

df = df.withColumn("visit_date", F.to_date("visit_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
```

First, get distinct dates, and use self join to get all dates combinations:

```
dates_df = df.selectExpr("visit_date as start_date").distinct().join(
    df.selectExpr("visit_date as end_date").distinct(),
    F.col("start_date") <= F.col("end_date"),
    "left"
)
```

Now, join the `dates_df` with the original dataframe and group by to count:

```
result = dates_df.join(
    df,
    (F.col("visit_date") >= F.col("start_date")) & (F.col("visit_date") <= F.col("end_date")),
    "left"
).groupBy("start_date", "end_date").agg(
    F.count_distinct("user_id").alias("unique_visitors")
).orderBy("start_date", "end_date")

result.show()

#+----------+----------+---------------+
#|start_date|  end_date|unique_visitors|
#+----------+----------+---------------+
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-01|              3|
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-02|              3|
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-03|              4|
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-04|              5|
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-05|              6|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-02|              1|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-03|              2|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-04|              3|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-05|              4|
#|2022-01-03|2022-01-03|              1|
#|2022-01-03|2022-01-04|              2|
#|2022-01-03|2022-01-05|              3|
#|2022-01-04|2022-01-04|              1|
#|2022-01-04|2022-01-05|              2|
#|2022-01-05|2022-01-05|              1|
#+----------+----------+---------------+
```